# Sufficient conditions on $M$ such that the intersection of infinitely many $\mathfrak{m} M$, $\mathfrak{m}$ maximal ideal, is zero?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a one-dimensional, noetherian and reduced ring. Let $M$ be a finitely generated and torsion-free $R$-module. I am looking for sufficient conditions on $M$ such that

$$\bigcap_{\mathfrak{m}} \mathfrak{m} M = 0$$
whenever $\mathfrak{m}$ runs through an **infinite** set of maximal ideals of $R$.

I was wondering if there is a well-known type of modules that satisfy this type of condition. This could be interpreted as follows: For every $m \in M$ the set of zeros of $m$ on $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is finite. Here the zeros of $m$ are given by those $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $m \in \mathfrak{m} M$.

Comment: Can you do this for a free module? Then can you reduce your question to this case? Hint: the natural map $M$ to its double dual is injective, since $M$ has no torsion.

Comment: @Mohan By what you are saying, I see that the statement is true for free modules and hence for those who can be embedded in a free module. Thus torsionless modules satisfy the statement. But torsion-free does not imply torsionless whenever the ground ring is not a domain. Am I missing something?